# CAAnimation redraw

Tags: ios, core-animation

I have a problem with disappearing objects after animation ends. It's all fine if animation gets to its end. But I have animation which is connected to `UIPanGesturerecognizer`. If user pans more than 33% of screen width, animation goes on. If not, animation gets `speed = -1` and actually gets to its beginning.

The question is: how to force layer to redraw?

When I try to start new animation, object appears.

I tried call `setNeedsDisplay:` in `- (void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)anim finished:(BOOL)flag`
, but with no luck.

**EDIT**

Here is some code. I put just one animation for the sake of cleanness. Everything works.

So, first, here is my gesture handler.

When the gesture is in `UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged` state, we stop the animation by setting layer's `speed` and control execution of animation by setting layer's `timeoffset`.

When the gesture is in `UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded` state, we have to check whether translation of pan on x is more than 33% of screen width. If it is we call `- (void)finishLayer:(CALayer*)layer animation:(CAKeyframeAnimation*)animation withForward:(BOOL)shouldGoForward`
 with `YES` which means animation should continue to next screen, otherwise, we pass `NO` which means animate backwards to inital state.

```
- (void)panGestureHandler:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)recognizer
{
    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
        //if our gesture was enough to let animation roll to its end
        if (fabsf(translation.x) > CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame) * 0.33)
        {
            [self finishLayer:categoryControllerMain.view.layer animation:menuOpenSwipeAnimateMoveLeft withForward:NO];
        }
        //finger movement was below .33% of screen width so animate to initial state
        else
        {
            [self finishLayer:categoryControllerMain.view.layer animation:menuOpenSwipeAnimateMoveLeft withForward:NO];

        }
    }
    else if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
    {
        //We put layer speed to zero so we can control animation with timeoffset in relation to finger pan movement
        categoryControllerMain.view.layer.speed = 0.0;
        [categoryControllerMain.view.layer addAnimation:menuOpenSwipeAnimateMoveLeft forKey:@"menuOpenMoveLeft"];
        categoryControllerMain.view.layer.timeOffset = fabs(translation.x / CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame));
    }
}
```

Here is the method which sends animation to its end by setting layer's `speed` back to value 1.0 or if we want to animate backwards, we set `speed` to -1.0. We also want to set `beginTime` so that after we end pan gesture, animation knows exact time from which to continue.

```
- (void)finishLayer:(CALayer*)layer animation:(CAKeyframeAnimation*)animation withForward:(BOOL)shouldGoForward
{

    pan.enabled = NO;
    if (shouldGoForward)
    {
        //animation continues
        CFTimeInterval pausedTime = [layer convertTime:CACurrentMediaTime() fromLayer:nil];
        layer.timeOffset = 0.0;
        layer.beginTime = 0.0;
        CFTimeInterval timeSincePause = [layer convertTime:CACurrentMediaTime() fromLayer:nil] - pausedTime;
        layer.beginTime = timeSincePause;
        layer.speed = 1.0;
    }
    else
    {
        //we want to take it back
        layer.timeOffset = [layer convertTime:CACurrentMediaTime() fromLayer:nil];
        layer.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime();
        layer.speed = -1;
    }
}
```

So, in case animation needs to run backwards, it really does, but when it's over, everything disappears. In case of forward animation, everything is in its place. After adding animation, I didn't change layer's `position`, and I don't use `fillMode` on animation, so after animation ends, everything should be as it was before animation started, everything happens on presentation layer of animation.

Here are some screenshots. There is pan gesture going on on first image. Since finger moves less than 33% of screen width, this where backwards animation should start. And it does. We animate `UITableView` which is empty now, white `UILabel` and grayish `UIImageView` in the background.

[image: Pan gesture in progress]

After pan gesture ends, animation starts rolling backwards and when it gets to its end, everything what animated just disappears. On the other hand, if we pan over 33% of screen width, animation gets forward and I can see my `UITableView`. Here is the photo of backwards animation end.
[image]

Comment: can you include your code and some screen shots please?

Comment: @MaxMacLeod Thanks for looking into it. I edited my post to explain further problem I'm having